# Arugula plural or singular?

Tags: singular

I've got this question in my mind. Is 'arugula' a plural name or singular? If it is plural does anybody know the singular form like arugulum or something like that? (well, it might be archaic, obsolete, etc)

Thanks!

Comment: augula is like coffee or tea, a mass or uncountable nouns. It is sold by the pound or kilo.

Comment: Well, I didn't ask for the plural form, but whether the word itself is plural (like Latin plural).

Comment: Do you know of any normal foodstuff that has a Latin form in normal use?

Answer (score 3):

Arugula is the name of the plant. It comes from an Italian dialect (arucola), which in turn comes from Latin (ērūca). So I believe the noun is singular and has no plural. You would say "five arugula plants," not "five arugulas," just as you would say "five rocket plants" and not "five rockets," or "five spinach plants" and not "five spinaches."

‘Most tender greens, such as arugula, spinach, watercress, and fresh herbs, need little or no cooking.’

Comment: This is what people where I live call rocket?

Comment: Yes, arugula is the same as rocket. I think arugula is more common in the US and rocket in the UK.

Comment: Thanks Lucie.
Got your point. Well, I already know it's uncountable. I was just curious if it was sort of plural word like chips. Yes, in common, you hardly ever hear someone says "Sir, your chips are ready", whereas it is correct and "Your chips is ready" is not correct! Nevertheless, the latter is in use! Many native speakers don't even know that chips is plural; like one chip, a lot of chips!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the OP is referring to certain words of Greek/Latin origin. The number of words that end with the plural suffix **-a** is very limited in English.

For example,

- words in the singular ending *-um*
  **[forum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forum#English)** (singular)
  **fora** (plural)
  **[bacterium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacterium#English)** (s)
  **bacteria** (p)
- words in the singular ending *-on*
  **[criterion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criterion#English)** (s)
  **criteria** (p)
  **[phenomenon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phenomenon)** (s)
  **phenomena** (p)

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-a#Suffix) notes

> Whereas the regular pluralization in English involves adding **-s** or **-es**, English words derived from a Latin/Greek etymon where the Latin/Greek would pluralize from **-on** (Greek) or **-um** (Latin) to **-a** do not always do so.  Usage of **-a** instead of **-s** differs between words: sometimes the two are interchangeable (e.g. *memorandums*/*memoranda*, *polyhedrons*/*polyhedra*), sometimes one is far more common than the other (e.g. *neurons* over *neura*, *automata* over *automatons*), and sometimes one is completely absent from usage (e.g. *bacteria* over *bacteriums*, *dendrons* over *dendra*)

As for the plant, in  Northern Italy where I live, it is commonly known as  *rucola*  but it's also called *[ruchetta](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/USATE/Sinonimi_e_Contrari/5/)* /ru'ket:a/, which happens to explain why it's *rocket* in the UK but *arugula* in the US. And just like in English the name of the plant is singular and uncountable.

There are other Italian loanwords ending in -a that are also uncountable, e.g. *mozzarella*, *marinara* and *carbonara* (sauce) but in the vast majority of of cases, Italian loanwords such as *dilemma*, *laguna*, *mafia*,  *orchestra*, *pergola*, *trauma* etc. form the plural by adding the suffix **-s** in English.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.